# Add multiple label dynamically in html page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I used following code for adding label dynamically.

```
  var array_resp=[CorrectStreet,CorrectCity,CorrectState,CorrectZip];
        // var stateName=map.getKey(CorrectState);
          if(array_resp.length > 0) {

                var answers = [];
                for(var i = 0; i <= array_resp.length - 2; i++) {

                    answers[i] = document.createLabel({
                        color : '#000',
                        text : array_resp[i],
                        top : top,
                        left : '30 px',
                        width : '420 px',
                        height : '100 px',
                        visible : 'true',
                        backgroundColor : 'white',
                        font : FontNormal,
                    });
                   document.body.appendChild(answers[i]);
                }
            }
```

in html:-

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

But it doesn't give correct output,when I am click on button. 
Why it happen? Can someone help me please.

Comment: Where is the myFunction()?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues in your code:

1. There are no function of `createLabel` for creating **LABEL** element
2. To assign the style / properties in wrong way, never in object type
3. There is no SPACE between 30 and px for left, width & height.

Try this:

```
<body>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
        var array_resp=['CorrectStreet','CorrectCity','CorrectState','CorrectZip'];
        // var stateName=map.getKey(CorrectState);
        if(array_resp.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i <= array_resp.length - 2; i++) {
                var label = document.createElement('label');
                label.style.color = '#000';
                label.style.top = 'top';
                label.style.left = '30px';
                label.style.width = '420px';
                label.style.height = '100px';
                label.style.visible = 'true';
                label.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                label.style.font = 'FontNormal';
                label.innerHTML = array_resp[i];

                document.body.appendChild(label);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
```